# XmlPullParser getting null instead of START_TAG

Tags: android, eclipse, xmlpullparser

I am trying to parse through an XML file but I am having issue with the document!

I am having issue with this line:

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "CarStatus");
```

but, I am getting null instead of START_TAG.

XML HTTP POST RESPONSE:

```
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270): <CarObject>
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270):   <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270):   <ResultMessage>success</ResultMessage>
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270):   <Cardata xsi:type="ArrayOfCarStatus">
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270):     <CarStatus> 
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270):       <CarID>241</CarID>
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270):       <CarName>ASC</CarName>
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270):     </CarStatus>
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270):   </CarData>
06-20 15:15:40.804: I/RESPONSE(2270): </CarObject>
```

Here is the code where I am having issue.

```
private CarStatus readCarStatus(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "CarStatus");
        String carId = null;
        String carName = null;

        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }

            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("CarID")) {
                carId = readCarId(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("CarName")) {
                carName = readCarName(parser);
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return new CarStatus(carId, carName);
    }

06-20 16:56:15.773: W/System.err(4017): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}CarStatus (position:START_TAG <ResultObject >@2:146 in java.io.InputStreamReader@415f04d8) 
06-20 16:56:15.773: W/System.err(4017):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2046)
06-20 16:56:15.773: W/System.err(4017):     at com.bentseytlin.maps.MainActivity.readCarStatus(MainActivity.java:174)
06-20 16:56:15.773: W/System.err(4017):     at com.bentseytlin.maps.MainActivity.parse(MainActivity.java:143)
06-20 16:56:15.773: W/System.err(4017):     at com.bentseytlin.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
06-20 16:56:15.773: W/System.err(4017):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-20 16:56:15.780: W/System.err(4017):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is 'Car' doing after '<CarStatus>'? I think your XML input is incorrect.

Comment: sorry, I dont know how that got there. the XML file is definitely not the issue!

Comment: Maybe you could skip the require call and do it like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187607/android-xmlpullparser-how-to-parse-this-xml-sample-file) thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use `require` incorrectly. I get the feeling you want it to tell you when the `START_TAG` is equal to `<CarStatus>`. But at each failed check the require method will throw an exception, meaning you have to add a try-catch block and the loop will be kind of weird. Please refer to [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) for further info.

I would personally not do it using reqiure but rather like I wrote in the comment above ([this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187607/android-xmlpullparser-how-to-parse-this-xml-sample-file)). I must however admit I have not done this in quite some time. :-)